# Android unable to destroy activity service not registered activity itself

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I'm making an Mp3 player that uses a service to be able to play music when the phone is closed or the app minimized. However, now when I go into an add playlist activity and try to get back to the main activity, I get the following error message:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity
{dv606.mp3player/dv606.mp3player.MP3Player}: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: 
dv606.mp3player.MP3Player$6@6ea6ce6
```

Which confuses me since it says that the main activity itself is the service which it is not. The "MusicService" is a separate class.

I use the following way to close the main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    appTerminated(isBound, connection);
}
```

appTerminated:

```
public static void appTerminated(Boolean b, ServiceConnection c) {
    if (b && c != null && musicservice != null) {
        musicservice.unbindService(c);
    }
}
```

connection is obtained as follows:

```
public static ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        musicservice = ((MusicService.MusicBinder) service).getService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        musicservice = null;
    }
};
```

isBound like this:

```
isBound = bindService(intentt, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

In my music service class i have these two methods as well:

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    MP3Player.appTerminated(MP3Player.isBound, MP3Player.connection);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    MP3Player.appTerminated(MP3Player.isBound, MP3Player.connection);
}
```

I am totally at a loss here, both because of the error message and also because I thought that this was the way to implement, bind and unbind a service from a main activity.

I guess I was wrong somewhere.

Comment: did you add the service in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yup, as follows:
<service
            android:name=".MusicService">
        </service>

Comment: I think the problem is in your service. Which run for some time and then it will stop running and stop your music player and make your object null. Try to trace out whether your service is running or not. try to print log.

Comment: I am sure that the service works fine when it's started because i can play songs for litterally hours without it stuttering or crashing. It only crashes when I go from my "AddPlaylistActivity" back to my "Mp3Player" (main) activity. However when I use the "back" button on my phone, it does not crash and simply toasts my error message if something goes wrong, while keeping the app alive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your `musicservice` is not null when you `unbind` it.